# keyup cannot be used on id but can be used on document

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an issue detecting the enter key event on a text box. I cannot seem to be using this

```
$("#serial").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
...
   }
});
```

But the keyup event can be detected if I use this

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
...
   }
});
```

which is a bit awkward as it will trigger the event if enter key being hit regardless the cursor position. Hopefully someone would have a pointer in this. Thanx :D

--- EDIT ---

I think it would be fair for me to include that I have these plugins on the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.image.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.link.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.table.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/tables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/tables/colResizable.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/forms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/autogrowtextarea.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/autotab.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.dualListBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.inputlimiter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/other/calendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/other/elfinder.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/plupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/plupload.html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/plupload.html4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/uploader/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.progress.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.colorpicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wizards/jquery.form.wizard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wizards/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.breadcrumbs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.collapsible.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.ToTop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.listnav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.sourcerer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.timeentry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ui/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/spinner/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/spinner/ui.spinner.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts/chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts/auto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts/bar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts/hBar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts/pie.js"></script>
```

Thing is .. I don't know if there's any of these which is unbinding the keyup event

Comment: Does the element exist when you are running that code? `alert(!!$("#serial").length)`

Comment: The document is always available, as the element in question probably is'nt. You're either missing a wrapping document.ready function or the element is dynamic.

Comment: @Jeebsion: I deleted my answer as you have ruled out dynamic elements. Try removing plug-ins 1-by-1 and see when it starts working. That's all I could suggest. You seem to have a lot of input plugins. It might be one of those.

Comment: okay .. I will do just that .. thanx btw Francois!

Comment: Posting a jsfiddle would also help.